# Can't implement extended TextView

Tags: android, runtimeexception, extending

I just found the AutoResizeTextView by Chase

[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds/5535672#5535672)

But I couldn't make it run yet.

```
AutoResizeTextView monologTextView;
monologTextView = (AutoResizeTextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogText);
```

xml:

```
 <AutoResizeTextView
                android:id="@+id/dialogText"
                style="@style/monologText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:singleLine="true"
                 />
```

Results in a android.view.InflateException.

```
Binary XML file line #44: Error inflating class AutoResizeTextView
```

When I change the XML to TextView

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialogText"
                style="@style/monologText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:singleLine="true"
                 />
```

I receive the following runtime exception:

android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to com.gootsproject.AutoResizeTextView

How can I implenent the extended textView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<AutoResizeTextView
                android:id="@+id/dialogText"
                style="@style/monologText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:singleLine="true"
                 />
```

you should indicate the complete path:

```
<com.gootsproject.AutoResizeTextView
```

Comment: I just figured it out myself. thank you anyway. I'll accept this answer.